# Using Return In another method

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the code snippet below I have created a Guid which I also want to use in other method:

```
public string MyActionName()
{
    Guid messageId = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    string guid = messageId.ToString();
    return guid;
}
```

I have tried

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = guid;
}
```

but I still cannot get it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the method like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = MyActionName();
}
```

You cannot reference to the local variable `guid` directly from outside because it is only visible inside the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change Label2.Text = guid; to Label2.Text = MyActionName();

The variable "guid" is declared inside of the function and cannot be used outside.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to assign an unique `guid` to the `Label2.Text` or use the same `guid` on multiple places?

If you want to reuse the function (create a new guid) you can implement the answer provided by Flat Eric.

If you want to create a `guid` and use the same `guid` on multiple places in your code. You need to store the result of the function in a variable and use that variable to assign other variables with the same `guid`.